# Error en sintaxis mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 0 AS temp
        UNION ALL SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT 2 
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 
        UNION ALL SELECT 4 
        UNION ALL SELECT 5
        UNION ALL SELECT 6  WHERE temp NOT IN (SELECT n_dia 
                                                      FROM estructura_horario 
                                                      WHERE n_status = 1 AND n_id_estructura_jornada=1);
```

Antes del `WHERE` me regresa la tabla temporal con números del 0 al 6 y en mi consulta mas interna me regresa números del 0 al 3.

Ahora el query que puse me debería arrojar del 4 al 6 ya que son lo que no estan en la consulta interna, pero al ejecutar marca error de sintaxis.
¿Que podría estar mal?

Comment: Creo que hay un error de sintaxis. la estructura de una sql 'union' es parecida a la siguiente: SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 UNION SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;

Comment: Puedes encontrar mas info en la siguiente pagina: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estas consultando sobre una columna `temp` del primer select, puedes agrupar esos Union en un Select, agregarle un alias `t` y luego de eso puedes agregar el where.

```
select temp from (SELECT 0 AS temp
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    ) as t
    where t.temp NOT IN (SELECT n_dia FROM estructura_horario 
                        WHERE n_status = 1 AND n_id_estructura_jornada=1)
```